# Default Document

Tags: php, content-management-system

OK, I'm trying to move a website from 1and1 for a client to a server they own. It's a PHP site. I have all the files moved over, the database moved over (including the files pointing to the new DB), and the front page is working fine (including hitting the DB).

However, none of the links work. They all point to non-existent folders. The site is some kind of CMS, maybe Wordpress, maybe not. But it's obvious that the folders in the links aren't really folders, but something for the program to key into in order to display the right content.

I say Wordpress because there is an old Wordpress DB, but as far as I can tell, nothing talks to it.

I can see in the DB a table called folders that contains all the non-existent folder names.

I'm guessing that it's a website setup issue. Maybe in the PHP.ini, or some other configuration.

Sorry if this sounds kinda vague. The client doesn't know what software it is, just how to use it. If you have any questions where I can you more detail, let me know.

Thanks

Index.php

```
<?php
/*
    Lite MVC Implementation

    HTTP requests should be redirected to this file if Apache can't find the page in the filesystem hierarchy.

    EDITING APP PAGES:
    PHP Page logic in /controller/
    HTML rendering in /views/
    Additional PHP classes autoloaded from /model/

    Edit URI path routes (mapping URL to page logic) by editing /application/router.class.php, function getController

    Hosting Requirements for CMS:
        * PHP 5.2.x and later as of February 2010
        * PECL Extension : HTTP (pecl_http) 
        * /protected/uploads should be writable by Apache
*/

    $site_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    define("__SITE_PATH__", $site_path);

    include("global/init.php");
    $registry->router = new Router($registry);
    $registry->router->setPath(__SITE_PATH__ . "/controller");
    $registry->router->loader();
?>
```

A sample folder would be 'services'. The record for this in the folders table is:

```
3   0   Services    services    Manage Services Content 0   2   2   1   0   2   0   2010-02-22 05:50:39 2010-03-09 13:26:13
```

.htaccess

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
#php_flag session.auto_start "On"
#php_flag display_errors "On"

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The list of db tables doesn't help really. Can you show a snippet of the homepage PHP including one of the links that doesn't work? Also, yes, the PHP.ini file might not be right but don't forget the .htaccess file, too.

Comment: Those aren't Wordpress tables.

Comment: Assuming apache, is mod_rewrite enabled / can you confirm that all requests to non-existing files and directories get redirected to `index.php`?

Comment: Windows IIS. Beyond that, I can't answer your questions. I write web apps, but setting up servers is a bit above me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the issue. Or I should say, someone else found it for me.

Just imported the rules of .htaccess into the website.

I was not aware that IIS doesn't use .htaccess, but instead uses web.config. I am now.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the

```
realpath
```

line. Was the old host a Linux-based host with maybe Apache and the new host is now Windows? It's possible the realpath function is not returning the right folder structure on the new host.

Is the site contained within the C:\inetpub\www folder on the host or is it elsewhere? If elsewhere, try moving the site into there or at least into a subfolder within c:\inetpub anyway.

Failing that, check this out http://david.steadson.com/2008/12/17/migrating-to-a-new-iis7-install-from-iis6/

Comment: Yes, the old site was Linux. And, yes, the new location on the Windows machine is C:\inetpub\www\... I'll experiment with the realpath tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: You were very close to the answer with the Linux/Windows question. You can see the answer I posted. Thanks.